# AWS Route-53, Lightsail and domain from 3rd party vendor

Tags: amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I have a domain from a 3rd party vendor that is attached to an AWS Lightsail instance. The nameserver for the domain has been changed from the vendor's to AWS' nameservers so that DNS records can be managed in the Lightsail console. This is working as expected, and the domain resolves to the correct IP

However, there is a need for adding additional records (CNAME for ownership verification to use the same domain for AWS SES, and MX + TXT records). These have been added in the Lightsail console area for DNS, but the records are not visible for DNS servers, even after 72 hours.

Being new to Lightsail, I have started suspecting that maybe the Lightsail DNS records are not meant to be used this way. Should this be done under AWS Route 53 -> Hosted zones instead? When creating a new hosted zone there, for this domain, it says to update nameservers to a different set of servers. If I go for Route 53, I assume I will have to assign the server's IP manually (when using Lightsail, it is assigned indirectly, through assigning the server instance to the domain).

My question is: What are the differences between managing DNS through Lightsail and Route 53 - and is there any benefit in using Lightsail other than this indirect assignment of server IP to the domain? RIs Lightsail just abnormally slow to propagate DNS changes? Route 53 also seems to have more options for DNS records (including TTL, which Lightsail does not have)